# Причины использования многоуровневых протоколов

Tags: протоколы, теория

> Назовите две причины использования многоуровневых протоколов?

Простой вопрос, для простого ответа :) Вопрос в учебном задании, что-то в гугле ответ не удалось найти. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под понятием "многоуровневый протокол". Если это идет в контексте моделей `OSI` и `TCP/IP` то я бы назвал модель многоуровневой, но никак не протокол. И в таком случае, используя многоуровневую модель вы получаете:

1. Возможность замены любого из уровней без надобности изменения любого другого уровня (если вы работаете на 4м уровне, вы гарантированно получите данные, предназначенные вашему уровню, от 3го, но так же вы обязаны передать на 5й правильные данные, правда уже при необходимости, и наоборот, если данные идут в обратном направлении). Например, среда передачи (1й уровень модели OSI) может заменяться чем угодно: радио, кабель и прочие, а более высокие уровни замены не требуют, вы все равно работаете с теми же IP-TCP (на сегодняшний день). Реализуется это все методами инкапсуляции и деинкапсуляции.
2. Гарантированная организация **логической связи** на каждом из уровней. Это значит, что, например, TCP уровень (4й) некоторого сервера связан непосредственно с TCP уровнем (4м) его клиента. Данные таким образом, при наличии того же протокола на приемной и передающей стороне смогут быть "распознаны" верно.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку осуществление взаимодействия между узлами в сети  - это сложная задача, ее необходимо по возможности упрощать. Универсальным подходом является - разбиение сложной проблемы на некоторое количество простых подпроблем. При этом каждая часть системы, отвечающая за решение конкретной проблемы, упрощается. Кроме того, при определении стыков взаимодействия между частями системы появляется возможность изменения отдельных частей без изменения всех остальных.

В этом и заключаются причины создания многоуровневых протоколов.